# Regex match for file and rename + overwrite old file

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Im trying to make a bash script to rename some files wich match my regex, if they match i want to rename them using the regex and overwrite an old existing file.

I want to do this because on computer 1 i have a file, on computer 2 i change the file. Later i go back to computer 1 and it gives an example conflict so it saves them both.

Example file:

> acl_cam.MYI

Example file after conflict:

> acl_cam (Example conflit with .... on 2015-08-20).MYI

I tried a lot of thinks like rename, mv and couple other scripts but it didn't work.

the regex i should use in my opinion:

```
(.*)/s\(.*\)\.(.*)
```

then rename it to value1 . value2 and replace the old file (acl_cam.MYI) and do this for all files/directories from where it started

can you guys help me with this one?

Comment: Have you looked at the Linux `rename` command? If it's not in your distribution, you can download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have, if I understand your question correctly, is two part. (1) What is the correct regex that will match the error string and produce a filename?; and (2) how to use the returned filename to move/remove the offending file?

If the sting at issue is:

```
acl_cam (Example conflit with .... on 2015-08-20).MYI
```

and you need to return the MySQL file name, then a regex similar to the following will work:

```
[ ][(].*[)]
```

The stream editor `sed` is about as good as anything else to return the filename from your string. Example:

```
$ printf "acl_cam (Example conflit with .... on 2015-08-20).MYI\n" | \
  sed -e 's/[ ][(].*[)]//'
acl_cam.MYI
```

(shown with line continuation above)

Then it is up to you how you move or delete the file. The remaining question is where is the information (the error string) currently stored and how do you have access to it? If you have a file full of these errors, then you could do something like the following:

```
while read -r line; do

    victim=$( printf "%s\n" "$line" | sed -e 's/[ ][(].*[)]//' )

    ## to move the file to /path/to/old
    [ -e "$victim" ] && mv "$victim" /path/to/old

done <$myerrorfilename
```

(you could also feed the string to `sed` as a **here-string**, but omitted for simplicity)

You could also just delete the file if that suits your purpose. However, more information is needed to clarify how/where that information is stored and what exactly you want to do with it to provide any more specifics. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you for the good reply David! The sed function is working but i cannot use MV to replace the files (files are in same folder) do you have a solution for that

Comment: Was not yet done, i wanted to say: Thank you for the good reply David! The sed function is working but i cannot use MV to replace the files (files are in same folder) do you have a solution for that? there is no error file just a almost identical file named ..(example confi..)

Comment: Yes, the answer is `mv -f "$victim" /path/to/old` (which forces the move) or `cp -a "$victim" newname; rm  "$victim"`. (a two-step copy/delete)

Answer (score 0):

Final solution for this question for people who are interested:

```
for i in *; do
   #Wildcar check if current file containt (Exemplaar
   if [[ $i == *"(Exemplaar"* ]]
    then
      #Rename the file to the original name (without Exemplaar conflict)
      NewFileName=$(echo "$i" | sed -E -e 's/[ ][(].*[)]//')
      #Remove the original file
      rm $NewFileName;
      #Copy the conflict file as the original file name
      cp -a "$i" $NewFileName;
      #Delete the conflict file
      rm "$i";
      echo "Removed file: $NewFileName with: $i";
    fi
done
```

I used this code to replace my database conflict files created by dropbox sync with different computers.